# List with odd_even function

Tags: python, list

When my program is done printing 10 random numbers, it should print something like this. (These numbers 3, 7, and 10 are just used as example.)

**List had 3 evens and 7 odds**

**The 3rd element in sorted nums is 10**

For some reason this isn't happening for me. 
This is the code I have so far:

```
import random

nums =[]

for i in range (1,11):
    x = random.randint(1,50)
    nums.append(x)

print(nums)

nums.sort()

print(nums)

start = nums[0:5]

print(start)

finish = nums[7:10]

print(finish)

def evenOdd(num):
    odd = 0
    even = 0
    for x in num:
        if (x % 2 == 0):
            even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1

print('List had', even, 'evens and', odd, 'odds')

print('The 3rd element in sorted nums is', num[2])
```

When I run it, this is what the program displays:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[7, 21, 6, 14, 22, 8, 24, 20, 26, 27]
 line 35, in <module>
[6, 7, 8, 14, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 27]
print('List had', even, 'evens and', odd, 'odds')
[6, 7, 8, 14, 20]
NameError: name 'even' is not defined
[24, 26, 27]
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. For example, how you create `nums` is irrelevant, though FWIW it could be simplified to `nums = [random.randint(1, 50) for _ in range (1, 11)]`

Comment: You never call `evenOdd`, and the variables defined in it are local-only

Comment: @sparx, probably just a problem of indentation. Print statements should be part of function. And you can call the function afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of problems in your code.  You aren't actually calling your `evenOdd` function, if you did call it, you have provided no way to get its results, and you have some variable name mismatches.  Also, your `evenOdd()` function wasn't doing the right thing because the `else` clause needed to be indented to be within the `for` loop.  The way it is in your version, `odd` will always be 1:

Here's code that fixes all of these issues:

```
import random

nums =[]

for i in range (1,11):
    x = random.randint(1,50)
    nums.append(x)

print(nums)

nums.sort()

print(nums)

start = nums[0:5]

print(start)

finish = nums[7:10]

print(finish)

def evenOdd(num):
    odd = 0
    even = 0
    for x in num:
        if (x % 2 == 0):
            even += 1
        else:
            odd += 1
    return even, odd

even, odd = evenOdd(nums)

print('List had', even, 'evens and', odd, 'odds')

print('The 3rd element in sorted nums is', nums[2])
```

The main thing here is that the `evenOdd` function returns a "tuple" that contains the resulting counts of odd and even numbers so that you can use them outside the function.

Sample result:

```
[2, 36, 20, 32, 6, 40, 39, 27, 24, 47]
[2, 6, 20, 24, 27, 32, 36, 39, 40, 47]
[2, 6, 20, 24, 27]
[39, 40, 47]
('List had', 7, 'evens and', 3, 'odds')
('The 3rd element in sorted nums is', 20)
```

Comment: Where "List had"... printed part, 7 + 1 is 8. Thats not reporting all 10 of the numbers in the list.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Didn't see that problem in the OPs code.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the last print statements ought to be in your `evenOdd` function, in which case your code isn't properly indented. It should be like this:

```
def evenOdd(num):
    odd = 0
    even = 0
    for x in num:
        if (x % 2 == 0):
            even += 1
        else:
            odd += 1
    print('List had', even, 'evens and', odd, 'odds')

    print('The 3rd element in sorted nums is', num[2])
```

After that, you can call the function thus:

```
evenOdd(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the variables `even` and `odd` globally - they're only available inside the function.

```
even = 0
odd = 0

# ...

def evenOdd(num):
    global even
    global odd
    even = 0
    odd = 0
    # ...
```

Comment: If i do this, then i get this error:     print('The 3rd element in sorted nums is', num[2])
NameError: name 'num' is not defined

Comment: `num` is a parameter in the `evenOdd` function. You'd probably want to return it, or also make it global.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also, :-

```
import random

nums =[random.randint(1,51,) for var in range(1,11)]  # creating nums list by short method
nums.sort()
print(nums)

def evenOdd(num):
    odd = 0
    even = 0
    for x in num:
        if (x % 2 == 0):
            even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1
    return even,odd

even,odd = evenOdd(nums)
print('List had', even, 'evens and', odd, 'odds')
print('The 3rd element in sorted nums is', nums[2])
```

I hope you learn something new.